# The Ionic Native social sharing plugin keeps having issues with rxjs. What can I do to fix this issue?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, capacitor, socialshare

I have made a stackblitz project with the issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-yngs1m?file=src/app/app.component.css

Whenever I try to use this plugin I get a rxjs error about incompatibility with Ionic Native. Ive tried installing it with --force and --legacy-peer-deps, and downgrading rxjs, which doesnt even work. Whatever I do, rxjs is always version 7.8.0.

To recreate this issue yourself in your own environment:

1. Create a new blank Ionic project with Angular
2. Install the `@ionic-native/social-sharing@4` plugin with `npm i @ionic-native/social-sharing@4`.
3. Import the plugin in your component with: `import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing'`.
4. Instantiate SocialSharing in the constructor with: `private socialSharing: SocialSharing`

In my case, when I run the app I already get issues with rxjs.

5. Add the following code to the ts in a method (in my case `share() {}`):

`let options = { subject: "Subject", message: "Message" }`

`this.socialSharing.shareWithOptions(options);`

Let me know if you know a way to fix this issue. My goal is to be able to share images using their local path. Clicking the share button will call the `share()` method and bring up the native share window for IOS and Android where users can select which platform they want to use to share the image

Answer (score 3):

`@ionic-native` is deprecated and was donated to the community. It’s now called `@awesome-cordova-plugins`, and versión 6 of it includes compatibility with latest rxjs.

Replace any `@ionic-native/whatever` package with its equivalent `@awesome-cordova-plugins/whatever`