# Unable to install plugins in Ionic Project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, capacitor

I started a new ionic app project. And tried to install plugins like appminimize, and other capacitor plugins.

But, It keeps showing me weird errors. First im getting ERESOLVE error for rxjs. I tried to install various versions of rxjs. The Build sometimes showing error that rxjs/observable is not found. (Its removed in new version of rxjs)

Overall this project is not going anywhere except the ui. Could you please guide me what is going wrong in it.[Error 1[image: ][1]]

[image: Error 2]

Comment: You should use the same syntax as the error. which says you should use `^7.4.0`

Comment: Try using the latest version of the app minimise package, 4.20.0 is not compatible with ionic 6

Comment: Hi Bart, how do I install the latest version (5.x)..... The npm install command shown on ionic website is only installing 4.x

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Ionic Native social sharing plugin keeps having issues with rxjs. What can I do to fix this issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75471490/the-ionic-native-social-sharing-plugin-keeps-having-issues-with-rxjs-what-can-i)

Answer (score 1):

Use `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`.  It tells NPM to ignore peer deps and proceed with the installation anyway. Fore more details [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh).